# turning list of dictionaries into geopandas geometry

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am struggling to solve this and have been working for a solution for several days now with no luck.

I have a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame which contains a column named `geometry`. This column consists of a list of dictionaries, in which there are two key:value pairs representing lat/long coordinates for nodes in a linestring. For example:

```
[{'lat': 35.0048032, 'lon': -106.0116078}, {'lat': 35.0048599, 'lon': -106.0120824}, 
 {'lat': 35.0048758, 'lon': -106.0122844}, {'lat': 35.0048971, 'lon': -106.0124856}]
```

I need to get this column to be recognized as a geopandas geometry column, but need to format it correctly to do so. I have tried to create a small function to do this. I tested the function on a sample list of dictionaries outside of a geodataframe. The function is this:

```
geom_list = [{'lat': 35.0048032, 'lon': -106.0116078}, {'lat': 35.0048599, 'lon': -106.0120824}, 
             {'lat': 35.0048758, 'lon': -106.0122844}, {'lat': 35.0048971, 'lon': -106.0124856}]

def dict_list_to_tuple_list(input_list):
    geom_flat = []
    for pair in input_list:
        lat_long = (pair['lat'], pair['lon'])
        geom_flat.append(lat_long)
    return geom_flat

new_geom = dict_list_to_tuple_list(geom_list)

print(new_geom)
```

output:

```
[(35.0048032, -106.0116078), (35.0048599, -106.0120824), 
 (35.0048758, -106.0122844), (35.0048971, -106.0124856)]
```

This seems like it would have solved the issue, however when I attempt to apply this to the actual geodataframe, I get an error. The geodataframe is named `results_gdf`, and the column with the list of dictionaries is `geometry`. I implemented the function as such:

```
# create a new column in the `results_gdf` geodataframe which holds the processed geometry field
results_gdf['geometry_new'] = dict_list_to_tuple_list(input_list=results_gdf['geometry'])
```

However, when I run this, I get the following a type error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dan\scripts\testing.py", line 76, in <module>
    results_gdf['geometry_new'] = dict_list_to_tuple_list(input_list=results_gdf['geometry'])
  File "C:\Users\dan\scripts\testing.py", line 71, in dict_list_to_tuple_list
    lat_long = (pair['lat'], pair['lon'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I then tried the dictionary `.get()` method like this:

```
def dict_list_to_tuple_list(input_list):
    geom_flat = []
    for pair in input_list:
        lat_long = (pair.get('lat'), pair.get('lon'))
        geom_flat.append(lat_long)
    return geom_flat
```

But got this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

This leads me to believe for some reason its reading the `pair` iterable as a list. But I'm not sure why this would be happening. I did also try doing `dict_pair = dict(pair)`. But was getting some weird results with that. So I'm drawing a blank here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. In particular, people need some of your data to answer this question.

Comment: Are you sure that *all* of your data is formatted this way? Your code looks fine to me at first glance, but if there were a list mixed in there with the dictionaries you’d see this error. You could also use pandas for this as an intermediate step, e.g. `parsed = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['geometry']); df['geometry'] = geopandas.points_from_xy(parsed.lon, parsed.lat)`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado , I did a check to see if there were any non-dictionary objects contained within the lists, and there were not.  I attempted to use your solution but got another error: 
`parsed = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results_gdf['geometry']); results_gdf['geometry'] = gpd.points_from_xy(parsed.lon, parsed.lat)` 
>>> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'lon'`

Comment: @KotaMori
this link is a sample of the dataset. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf18wvfyv6d1kob/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: Try the first of the two lines I sent you and look at the dataframe and see if you can debug yourself

Comment: @dan_the_dam_man You should add the data to the script so people do not have to download the file and guess the method you load the data. Plus, clicking a hyperlink can be insecure.

Answer (score 1):

The key to the answer was provided by @michaelDelgado:

```
# create a dataframe from the geometry column
parsed = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results_gdf['geometry'])

# extract the coordinate pairs from each dictionary
parsed2 = parsed.applymap(lambda x: [x['lat'], x['lon']], na_action='ignore')

# concatenate the extracted coordinate pairs to a new column containing a list of lists of coord pairs
parsed2['geom_new'] = parsed2.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)

# join the newly converted column to the original gdf
new_geom_col = parsed2['geom_new']
results_gdf = results_gdf.join(new_geom_col)

# convert the new column into a shapely linestring object
results_gdf['linestring'] = results_gdf['geom_new'].apply(lambda x: LineString(x))

# set the GDFs geometry column = to the new linestring column
results_gdf.set_geometry(col='linestring', crs="EPSG:4326", inplace=True)
```